# Get all child items under either Sitecore template A or template B

Tags: templates, sitecore

Is there a way to target all child pages under two templates? As in, if template name is "A" or if template name is "B", get the children?

This is what I have, and it only targets one template right now but I want to add some sort of or to it so I can get the child items of another:

```
    Item ContentGroup = CurrentItem.Axes.SelectSingleItem(@"child::*[@@templatename='Section Page']/*[@@templatename='Sub Page Top Level']");
```

I went to get all child items for templates with the name "Sub Page Top Level" OR "Sub Page Top Level Custom." Is there a way to do this without too much trouble?

Answer (score 5):

You can use logical operator like `or`:

```
/*[@@templatename='Sub Page Top Level' or @@templatename='Sub Page Top Level Custom']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Linq you can use :

```
homeItem.Axes.GetDescendants().Where(x =>(x.TemplateID.ToString().Equals(yourId1) || x.TemplateID.ToString().Equals(yourId2));
```

You can also evaluate your sitecore queryes using Sitecore XPath Builder:
  To get all items under home item  based on 2 templates use:

```
/sitecore/content/home//*[@@templateid='{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}' or @@templateid='{075AB719-9D9C-4ED0-9100-545E87D830A0}' ]
```

I suggest you to use templateid not templatename. Few years ago I made some tests and is much faster queries using templateid

Comment: I don't know if they updated the API or something, but `GetDescendants` no longer takes any parameters.

Comment: GetDescendants takes longer time to load. Is there any way using GetChildren method ?

Comment: @gretro you don't pass any arguments to GetDescendants but use a linq query instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post has been inactive for a couple of months.

I would like to start by saying that I'm no Sitecore expert, but since I had to face the problem, here is how I solved my issue. I wanted to make sure I reduced the number of calls and the size of those calls to the database because my solution will live in Azure.

```
var path = rootItem.Paths.Path;

var query = String.Format("fast:{0}//*[@@templateid='{1}' or @@templateid='{2}']",
            path, CategoryItems.CategoryLandingPageTemplateId, CategoryItems.CategoryPageTemplateId);

var items = GetSitecoreDatabase().SelectItems(query);
```

As you can see, I used a fast query. This works for immediate children, but you could also modify the query to get descendants. This should work fine if you know your query will return 1000 items or less. Otherwise, I would use the Search engine (Lucene or Solr) to get to those items.